# Check last database usage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the last time any record changed in a specific Sql Server 2000 database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201990/how-can-i-determine-the-last-time-any-record-changed-in-a-specific-sql-server-20)

I've been asked by my employer to migrate all of the currently used databases from one server to another and then "archive" all of the databases no longer being used.

The problem I'm having is that there's little to no documentation as to which applications are making use of which databases on the server and there's not much convention to the name scheme either.  Unfortunately, we "support" a lot of third party software here and things are messy, to say the least.

The approach which I'd like to use would be to migrate any databases that have seen transactions within the last month or so and then just offline and backup the others.

The problem I have is that I'm not sure how to check for activity on a given database?  Is there something I can use that tells me if anything has been going on?

Comment: This may help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/how-can-i-tell-if-a-sql-server-database-is-still-being-used

Comment: Thanks, Ken.  It does look like this is a duplicate question.  I've voted to close it.

Answer (score 1):

To check current activity [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) is excellent.  However aside from any logging that may have been carried out I fear this is all you can do.

However I usually find that setting the suspect databases to offline usually causes any problems to show themselves ;-)

Comment: I don't know that I agree that Profiler is "excellent" - it is pretty good at bringing your server to its knees, if you're not careful. If you want to measure activity over a longer period of time, I would suggest that a server-side trace is vastly better (and more "excellent"). Use Profiler to configure the trace, but don't use Profiler to run the trace, watch the activity as it streams on your desktop, etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Fair point - I've upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000 unfortunately there is not much you can do about this. SQL Server doesn't track this on its own in a convenient way for you to just run a query. You could set up a server-side trace for a day or a week, then pull the data from the trace and group by database_id to see which databases have been touched in that period.

Shutting off access and waiting for people to complain is the wrong way IMHO. First, what if you deny access to a critical database? What about a database that is only accessed at month end? What if the only person who uses that database is on vacation? If you shut off access and you can turn it back on fairly quickly, this might be ok, but I'd be very careful about that approach.

In SQL Server 2005 and above you could query DMVs in each database like sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, which tell you the last user seek / scan / update. You can also set up simple audits. [I blogged about this here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed) (even though it might not help you right now).